# What is this plant with strap-like leaves and a yellow-orange spear shaped flower bud?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image][image: Picture of the plant]

I bought this flower plant 2 days ago. But I don't know the name of the flower. Can anyone pls tell me the name?[image]

Comment: I would say that flower still isn't fully open - if it opens more, post another shot.

Comment: Can it be bird of paradise? I thought bird of paradise flowerhas a long blue lip like structure like a bird? But this flower has nothing like this:(

Comment: No, its not Strelitzia reginae (Bird of Paradise), flowers are not like this.

Answer (score 3):

Same story as the other plant you asked about - that's a bud and it will open when the time is right. Patience my friend... as to what it is, it looks a bit like Strelitzia reginae (Bird of Paradise plant) from the leaves - except the bud shape is wrong. If no one else knows what it is, please post another photo when the flower has opened.

UPDATED ANSWER:

Yes, got it, having seen the new photograph - it's Heliconia psittacorum 'Andromeda' and its not quite finished opening fully yet. It's a perennial  native to the Caribbean and the north of South America, but also often listed as a Malaysian plant. The common name for this plant is Parrot Plant, though that also refers to other varieties of Heliconia.

Comment: Actually I was trying to find bird of paradise.

Comment: @trina: Bird of Paradise is just another name for Strelitzia.

Comment: Bamboo this is the latest picture of the flower. Can u identity it?

Comment: @trina - see updated answer

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but is this a type of orchid?

Comment: @trina - no, its not, its in a separate family of its own - was once grouped in with musa, or banana, but is actually related to the zingerberales, a group which includes the gingers.